# useEffect hook fix dependency array when a route is changed

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing a problem with the functional component. I'm using a `react-router-dom` package for handling the routes. What I have is a list that contains links and buttons and when we click on the button a dropdown is opened. This dropdown also contains links.

- Whenever user will change the route all dropdowns will close.
- Whenever new dropdown is opened all others will also close.

**How I'm manging the state of these dropdowns?**

I'm treating the state of every dropdown as a separate object and `onClick` listener will pass a `key` / `property` as an argument that has a boolean value. Based on that value a class will be added on the dropdown.

I already achieve this with the help of a class component.

**Class component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class ToggleClass extends Component {
    state = {};

    toggle = dropdownName => {
        // If it has the true value then turn into false, It is a behavior of a toggle.
        if (this.state[dropdownName]) {
            this.setState({ [dropdownName]: false });
        }
        // If there is not any dropdown is opened it means state object is empty
        // Object.keys will return an empty array then please open that dropdown.
        else if (Object.keys(this.state).length === 0) {
            this.setState({ [dropdownName]: true });
        }
        // Else block will ony trigger when the user clicked on other dropdown,
        // then close the last dropdown and just open the new one
        else {
            Object.keys(this.state).forEach(i => {
                this.setState({ [i]: false });
            });
            this.setState({ [dropdownName]: true });
        }
    };

    onRouteChanged = () => {
        // Take a state object and convert all its keys into an array
        // and set it to false whenever a route changes.
        Object.keys(this.state).forEach(i => {
            // pageMenu: false
            this.setState({ [i]: false });
        });
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
            this.onRouteChanged();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.onRouteChanged();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list">
                <li>
                    <Link to="/link1">Link 1</Link>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <button onClick={() => this.toggle("dropdown1")}>Dropdown 1</button>

                    <ul className={this.state["dropdown1"] ? "open" : "hide"}>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/link2">Link 2</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/link3">Link 3</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <button onClick={() => this.toggle("dropdown2")}>Dropdown 2</button>

                    <ul className={this.state["dropdown2"] ? "open" : "hide"}>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/link4">Link 4</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/link5">Link 5</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(ToggleClass);
```

But the problem is on the functional component by using hooks. `react-router-dom` has a hook named [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) which returns the current `pathname`. But `onRouteChanged` function is updating the state. I cannot use this function inside `useEffect` hook it turns into an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
  onRouteChanged();
}, [location, onRouteChanged]);
```

But If I remove the `onRouteChanged` from the dependency array then linter will warn about this

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'onRouteChanged'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

```
useEffect(() => {
  onRouteChanged();
}, [location]);
```

**Functional Component:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const ToggleFunc = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  const onRouteChanged = () => {
    Object.keys(state).forEach(i => {
      setState({ [i]: false });
    });
  };

  const toggle = dropdownName => {
    if (state[dropdownName]) {
      setState({ [dropdownName]: false });
    } else if (Object.keys(state).length === 0) {
      setState({ [dropdownName]: true });
    } else {
      Object.keys(state).forEach(i => {
        setState({ [i]: false });
      });
      setState({ [dropdownName]: true });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onRouteChanged();
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <ul className="list">
      <li>
        <Link to="/link1">Link 1</Link>
      </li>

      <li>
        <button onClick={() => toggle("dropdown1")}>Box 1</button>

        <ul className={state["dropdown1"] ? "open" : "hide"}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link2">Link 2</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link3">Link 3</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <button onClick={() => toggle("dropdown2")}>Box 2</button>

        <ul className={state["dropdown2"] ? "open" : "hide"}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link4">Link 4</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/link5">Link 5</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default ToggleFunc;
```

Can you guide me What is the optimal way to fix these errors?

[Full example Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/solo98989-vjgi0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to refactor the structure of the state and the toggle implementation, here is the fixed sandbox example (I didn't changed the state structure just fixed your issue).

https://codesandbox.io/s/solo98989-q11j1

Comment: Thanks for the answer could you explain your code of the `onRouteChanged` function? What is the correct way to store the sate of different dropdowns?

Comment: I wrapped onRouteChanged function using useCallBack hook with empty deps, this means it will be initiated only once, but in order to use latest state in our function we can pass arrow function state => something to setState function, this will ensure that inside the passed arrow function state will be the latest. So at last I just reduced the keys and got new state with the same key but false value.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge. One last question Is storing dropdowns some like this is good or not?

Comment: I think it is better to change the state with something like this: {"activeDropDown":(here name of the active drop down for example "dropdown1")}

Comment: My implementation of react `onRouteChange` with `useCallback` saying pass `state` on the dependency array, But why your implementation of `useCallback` linter doesn't say pass `state` on the dependency array. Please explain this.

Comment: Because in your implementation you access state, but in my implementation I pass function to setState with argument state. I am not directly accessing state, so I don't need to add state in the dependency array. Please see the detailed setState  explanation here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate.